# Executin Specific JUnit Test Case using Maven Command

Tags: java, windows, maven, junit

I have written a new JUnit Test case which I want to compile using maven command. I am trying to execute this command from the location which has `pom.xml` and this is the command-

```
mvn -Dtest=src\test\java\absolute\path\of\JUnit\test\hello_Test.java test
```

and this is the output I got (says there are no tests to run)-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-maven-component
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 81 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 85 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\projects\absolute\path\of\maven\component\my-maven-component\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 04 13:53:08 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: if you try to run with simply -Dtest=hello_Test would that work?

Comment: you mean to remove the `absolute path` and `.java` extension? No it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry. It worked. The command failed previously because of typographical error I had made.

Comment: ok, to not leave the question unanswered, I will answer with the working solution then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the full path to run a specific test, the value of the `test` option is actually a pattern.

As from [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

> Specify this parameter to run individual tests by file name, overriding the includes/excludes parameters. Each pattern you specify here will be used to create an include pattern formatted like **/${test}.java, so you can just type "-Dtest=MyTest" to run a single test called "foo/MyTest.java". The test patterns prefixed with a ! will be excluded.

So you can even simply run:

```
mvn -Dtest=hello_Test test
```

Or double check your input in case any typo was made (as per your comment).